# AES/Rijndael: search on encrypted data - static salt and IV

Tags: encryption

I want to do searching on encrypted data. Which means that there is the need to have the same ciphertext every time I encrypt the same plaintext. I.e. think of a list of encrypted names and I want to find all "Kevin"'s in it. I would now encrypt "Kevin" and search the database for the encrypted text. All hits will be "Kevin"'s — but still only the one who has the password knows.

Now my question: What about security if I use the same salt and IV (to get the effect described above) all the time? Is the encryption still secure? Or is there any other method to do searching on encrypted data?

Comment: Do you want to search for strings containing "Kevin" somewhere, or do you only want to compare the full message?

Comment: I want to compare the full message! To my mind checking if "Kevin" would be <somewhere> in the text would quite the same: One had to build an encrypted word-list of the texts. In which at the end a 1:1 search for the encrypted word ("Kevin") should habe been done. Or do you know any smarter approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do a deterministic encryption then you should use an encryption mode
that has been designed for deterministic encryption (and not modify an encryption mode designed for something else).

One possibility is the SIV encryption mode described in
[RFC 5297](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5297).

(Of course, deterministic encryption has its drawbacks, but discussing this is not part of this question.)

Comment: Do you know if there is any implementation for JavaScript?

Comment: I'm not aware of any JavaScript implementation. Crypto in JavaScript often means doing it in the wrong layer, hence crypto libraries in JavaScript are rare.

Comment: Crypto on the client side is the only chance you have to get "host proof hosting". So why "the wrong layer"?

Comment: What are you using to send the JavaScript code securely to the client? You need a secure channel to do this. But if you already have a secure channel to deliver code, then why don't you used this channel to exchange all the data? This often translates to either you use SSL, then you don't have to encrypt using JavaScript or you don't use SSL and then the JavaScript encryption does not help against man-in-the-middle attacks either.

Comment: To make the last comment clear. There are a few applications where doing crypto in JavaScript is OK, and your application may be one of them. But these applications are rare and so are reliable crypto libraries in JavaScript.

Comment: Assume that due to legal issues plaintext data is not allowed to leave the client. What could be the problem if JS code is not transferred via a secure channel?